# Responsive Viewport - Not working on tablet

Tags: responsive-design, viewport

I have a website that is 1070 pixels wide.  I am using the following viewport tag...

```
<meta name="viewport" width="1070" content="initial-scale=1" >
```

If I understand correctly, this should display the page in full on any device.  But if I try and view the page on a tablet the page always needs to be zoomed out.

Anyone help?

Comment: Try <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Surely thats completely the opposite of what i am trying to achieve?

Comment: that is what I use and it works for every device.

Answer (score 2):

With `<meta name="viewport" width="1070" content="initial-scale=1" >` you are telling that device's viewport to be 1070 pixels.

> "If I understand correctly, this should display the page in full on
>   any device. But if I try and view the page on a tablet the page always
>   needs to be zoomed out."

No, you are telling the device to display in 1070, hence having to zoom out (assuming tablet in portrait mode).

Is your site responsive at all? What are your break points? Or is it static at 1070? If your site is optimize for mobile viewing (responsive), then you use

> A typical mobile-optimized site contains something like the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size or position based on the viewport height.)

The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

The iPhone and many popular Android phones have 3- to 4-inch (7–10 cm) screens with 320—480 pixels (~160 dpi). Firefox for Maemo runs on the Nokia N900, which has the same physical size but 480—800 pixels (~240 dpi). Because of this, the last version of Fennec displayed many pages about one third smaller (in actual, physical size) than iPhone or Android. This caused usability and readability problems on many touch-optimized web sites. Peter-Paul Koch wrote about this problem in A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Viewport is a virtual area to display your website, if you set width="1070", the tablet uses exactly 1070 pixels per row to display the site. So if the tablet has a width lower than 1070, you need to zoom out to display the whole page.

If you want the tablet to display the page in full, use `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"`, then whatever how wide your website is, it fills the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1070, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
```